# Node js cuncurrency strategy peculiarity

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

**Introduction:**

I am spending 5 month with developing node js application, and come up with concurrency issue, as I know in javascript there is no support of concurrency from the first version of language, because it was originally developed for browser interaction. When it comes to the server the concurrency was 'plugged' into language, people started run one process many times with linux utility, then cluster api was created and marked as unstable now, I suppose it does the same thing.

**Question:**

How the work of this type of concurrency differs from the concurrency which was created from first version of programming language, like C++ or Java, or dynamically typed language like Python? Is it has lower performance?

Answer (score -1):

In NodeJS, there is no concurrency at all. There is only one thread, the event loop,that simulate parallelisme. Just check on google, it's very good explained.